# angular karma test indefined id

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am trying to test parent child components, the parent test is successful but the child in which I am calling @output attribute in oninit is failing  "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

```
    export class SinglepostComponent implements OnInit {
               @Input() post: Post;
           @Input() posts: Array<Post>;
          public comments: Array<Comment>;
           public comm: Comment;
           constructor(
             private postService: PostService,
             private dataService: DataService,
             public dialog: MatDialog,
            public commentservice: CommentService
             ) { }

             ngOnInit() {
      this.postService.getComments(this.post.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.comments = data;
           });
             }
```

Comment: Share your spec file

Comment: thanks for you help Vikas i just solved by making an instance of the variable i'am using insted of just declaring it